# How to edit Table B when Insert/Edit table A

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-data

I am using Dynamic Data (Linq) to create an admin page. I have a table that contains users and a table that controls which account(s) users have access to.

UserAccess has foreign keys to User and Account

When I add a new user, or edit an existing user, I need to be able to set which accounts that user has access to, so I need to be able to access & modify the UserAccess table when I am inserting/Editing a user. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! We can help you solve your problem better if you [improve your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Can you supply some relevant code your working on? This gives us a better understanding of your problem. BTW where does ASP Classic fit in this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476583/how-do-i-make-a-manytomany-insert-template-for-ef-dynamic-data

Answer (score 1):

Several ways I can think of to set initial values:  You can set a UPDATE INSERT trigger in the DB that create a set of default UserAccess values.  Or you can trap the the System.Data.Linq.Changeset then when doing an Insert or Update of the object named User, fire off a Linq function to set initial values. 
In the application, you would have to remind the user to set up access when creating a new user.